# Checking array indexes when using literal subscripting

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsarray

As Apple suggests, we need to check the index of an `NSArray` before calling `objectAtIndex:`. To do this, we can use a category or method swizzling.

For this subscript syntax,

```
index = 1;
id person = pArray[index];
```

is there a way to implement that?
Of course, I can check `index` beforehand.

Comment: You want to check this for *every* array without opt out? That will add a lot of overhead and is definitely not need in most cases (for example when iterating over a range, or when the count is validated once after the array is received from the network or similar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler simply generates the fancy new syntax sugar into a call to `objectAtIndexedSubscript:`, so that would be the method you want to swizzle. As mentioned in my comment though, that will add a lot of overhead that you can't easily get out of after enforcing it.

Edit: One more thought on the overhead, `NSArray` already does that check internally and throws an exception when it comes out of bound. Maybe wrapping some blocks of code in `@try/@catch` blocks where it is sensible makes more sense for you?

Comment: ah, objectAtIndexedSubscript is what I want~

Comment: no need to care about why the exception happens and hence abandon using @try/catch.  If index is out of range, it gets a nil object which will be safe even sent a not found selector.